# How do I append data to the list in loop?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to add `AppGuid` and `AppName` to `httpResp` list in the loop with same index as current index that loop is running on so that I can get `httpResp` list which includes `AppGuid` and `AppName`, how I do that?

```
    var data = new List<GetBuildTempClass>();
    List<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject> httpResp = new List<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>();

    foreach (var app in data)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps/" + app.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
        var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>(json);

        if (model != null)
        {
            httpResp.Add(model);
        }
    }

    public partial class GetBuildTempClass
        {
            public Guid AppGuid { get; set; }
            public string AppName { get; set; }

        }

 public class BuildsClass
    {
        public class Data
        {
            public List<string> buildpacks { get; set; }
            public string stack { get; set; }
        }
        public class Lifecycle
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Data data { get; set; }
        }

        public class App
        {
            public string href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links
        {
            public App app { get; set; }
        }

        public class CreatedBy
        {
            public string guid { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
        }

        public class Resource
        {
            public string guid { get; set; }
            public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
            public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public object error { get; set; }
            public Lifecycle lifecycle { get; set; }
            public Links links { get; set; }
            public CreatedBy created_by { get; set; }
        }

        public class BuildsRootObject
        {
            public List<Resource> resources { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what happens when you do it this way?

Comment: I'm just getting `model` which contains a response from API but I also want AppName and Guid append to it.

Comment: Overload the Tostring() on the then you get a string back with the values you return or just + them … or what am I missing? also you might consider cashing this as you may get a few hits on this

Comment: @PPann I didn't get you.

Comment: @Sam, I do not understand your question append to a list is done by using List.Add(item),  you can add a item to a list<T> if you make T a tuple you can add tuple data so List<(Class1,Class2...)> then you do list.Add((myClass1,myClass2)); what are you trying to do?

Comment: For me the sample code does just nothing. It initializes an empty _List<T>_ and then loops over the list items wich are not there, so nothing is done. And then I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would like to have a  list of tuple

```
var httpResp = new List<(BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject rootObj,Guid AppGuid,string appName)>();
```

To add you do

```
httpResp.Add( (model,Guid.Parse(resource.Guid),resource.AppName));
```

You can access then via the tuple in a loop or as individual named variables or in the list via the index.

```
var name= httpResp[0].appName;
```

if knows the name as we created a named tuple. if you do not name them you get item1, item2,...  auto generated.